# Does runalltests run test cases for managed packages?

Tags: unit-test, managed-package

Does this parameter run all the test classes for the managed packages Or does it run only for the unmanaged packages ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does:

> Does "run-all-tests" includes running managed package tests?
>   - Yes

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003620&language=en_US